# Reload UITableView from a NSObject

Tags: ios, uitableview, timer, nsobject

I have a question concerning iOS. I couldn't find an answer to my question online but maybe one of you know the answer. 
Im working on an app which pulls data from an online database. A NSObject Class is called by a timer in the background of the app. I want it to tell one of my view controller to reload its tableview if it finds new data. Like it is supposed to check for data not caring in which view controller im in. But when I'm in the specific one with my table view it should reload the table view if it found new data.
I've tried to create an instance of the tableviewcontroller in my NSObject and call the reload table view function front there, but that doesn't work :/
I apologise for my poor explanation, I'm not a native speaker.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Reload data could change many things and be disruptive to the user if they aren't expecting a reload. Probably the best thing to do is have the NSObject Class send an alert message to reload data, then the user clicks ok. The NSObject Class can send the message to the viewController and if it's being viewed, run it's method natively, and if it's not being viewed, no need to reload.

Comment: Thank you for your responds :) That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two approaches:

1. post a NSNotification in your class that gets more data and observes
   this notification in your class that the TableView is initialized.
2. make a delegate approach between the two classes and fire a method when you have the new data.

I would go with the first option:

a. in your data loading class:

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"newDataFetched" object:anyObject];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

b. in your listener class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(aMethodToReloadTheTableView:)
               name:@"newDataFetched"
             object:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly. I thought of doing it with notifications, but I didn't know how to do it the right way! Thanks :)